# Creating multiple bundles in directory where it finds js file

Tags: webpack

My src structure is like this:

```
--src/
----index.js
----index.html
----background/
------background.js
------background.html
----editor/
------editor.js
------editor.html
```

I am new to webpack but I was able to get it to work with just index.js like this:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (env) {
    return {
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/web/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/web'),
            filename: 'index.bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/static/'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js']
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test:/\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/, loader:'string-replace-loader?search=^.*?console\.[a-zA-Z].*?$&flags=gm&replace=', enforce:'pre' },
                { test:/\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/, loader:'babel-loader' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from:'./src/web' },
            ], {
                ignore: ['*.js']
            })
        ]
    }
}
```

It properly spits out a index.bundle.js in the root directory. But I also want it to create a (1) background.bundle.js in the background directory and a (2) editor.bundle.js in the editor directory. Is it possible for it to auto detect the name and create a bundle in its respective directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change `entry` to a `object` to enable multiple entry.

```
{
    entry: {
        web: './src/web/index.js',
        background: './src/background/background.js',
        editor: './src/editor/editor.js'
    }
}
```

and change `output.filename` to

```
{
    output:{
        filename: '[name]/[name].bundle.js'
    }
}
```

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename for more details.

Comment: @Noitidart And you should add a `.babelrc` file to configure your `babel-loader`. see http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/ and https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/.

Comment: Thank you for that babel note. I was playing with this and it worked! However index.js was created in `web/index.bundle.js`, is it possible for index to remain in root rather then get into subdir?

Comment: @Noitidart I can not see the `web` directory，is it in `src` directory?In your question, the `index.js` is in `src`,not `src/web`.

Comment: Oops my mistake! Thanks so much this worked perfect!